# Tools/standards for transforming json of one format, to json of another format

Tags: javascript, json, go

I'm looking for a tool/standard that converts allows configurable translation of json from one format, to another.

For example, lets say I have a source json:

```
{
   "user": {
      "firstName": "bob", 
      "lastName" : "jones"
   }
}
```

And I wanted to be create creating json objects like:

```
{
   fName: "bob", 
   lName: "jones"
}
```

Then I might have a translation configuration like:

```
{
   mappings: [
      {
          from: "src.user.firstName",  
          to: "target.fName"
      }, 
      {
          from: "src.user.lastName",  
          to: "target.lName"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I'm really looking for is a standard that does this in multiple languages, but failing that, if you can suggest tools for Go and JavaScript.

Note also, that you might want to do things like:

- Extract values from arrays

Maybe like:

```
{
    mappings: [
       {
           from: "src.user.favoriteColors[0]", 
           to: "target.userFirstFavouriteColor", 
       }
    }
}
```

- Put values into arrays

eg. translating:

```
{
    userMap: {
       id1: {
           name: "bob"
       }, 
       id2: {
           name: "alice"
       }
    }
}
```

to:

```
   users: [
       {
           name: "bob"
       }, 
       {
           name: "alice"
       }   
    ]
}
```

With a configuration maybe like:

```
{
    mappings: [
       {
           from: "src.userMap.*", 
           to: "target.users[]", 
       }
    }
}
```

- Combine multiple values into one

eg. Maybe like:

```
{
    mappings: [
       {
           from: ["src.user.fName", "src.user.lName"], 
           to: "target.fullName", 
           stringFn: "{0} {1}"
       }
    }
}
```

I'm basically thinking XSLT but for json.

Does such a standard exist?

Comment: Probably everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask this question on SO within the context of the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) command line tool.

Just tag your question with `jq`. There are some jq experts on SO who can transform anything from any structure to any structure, with ease.

I have bookmarked and used a lot of their `jq` snippets myself.

You can define your own transformations and put them into functions in your $HOME/.jq directory.

For example, this transforms JSON to csv format.

```
def tocsv($x):
    $x
    |(map(keys)
        |add
        |unique
        |sort
    ) as $cols
    |map(. as $row
        |$cols
        |map($row[.]|tostring)
    ) as $rows
    |$cols,$rows[]
    | @csv;
```

With some tweets exported as `tweets.json` from the Twitter API, call this as

```
 <tweets.json jq  -s  -S \
  '[.[] \| {name:  .user.name, sn: .user.screen_name, loc: .user.location, url:.user.url, desc:.user.description, _fol: .user.followers_count }]'  \
  | jq  -f -r to_csv.jq
```

---

Another option is the newly-released (July 2022) ["Invisible XML"](https://invisiblexml.org/), which is also a draft W3C Standard. I haven't used ixml, but maybe someone else has applied it on JSON data.

this is its pitchline, from the inVisibleXML [Tutorial](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/ixml/tutorial/tutorial.xhtml):

> "We choose which representations of our data to use, JSON, CSV, XML, or whatever, depending on habit, convenience, or the context we want to use that data in.
> [...]
> Invisible XML (ixml) is a method for treating non-XML documents as if they were XML, enabling authors to write documents and data in a format they prefer while providing XML for processes that are more effective with XML content."

Comment: I think JQ is valid answer. One could always write a node utility package around it.